# Display multiple line error messages on record update in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to display multiple line messages error message when user updates a field `Asset code` on case record in lightning environment.

I tried with `trigger.addError('Error line 1 <br/>' + 'Error line2', false)` in apex class. It works in classic but `html` tags are not supported in Lightning.

Is there any way to display message/toast to display error message only when `Asset code` gets changed on case record detail page .

Comment: Did you try new line character \n?

Comment: It doesn't work since `\n' is a html tag which is not supported in lightning

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom component or is it a standard lightning page ? If custom component, you could send the error message as a map and render it using showToast event / ui:message component.

Comment: It's a standard lightning page, not a custom lightning component.